# How to filter apache access log using awk or sed or cut

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut

This is my apache access log file. I want apache access log uniq count for urls.

```
"2011-09-07 17:00:00" "GET /abc/index.php/contentapi/discontent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/"
"2011-09-07 17:00:17" "GET /abc/index.php/contentapi/discontent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:21" "GET /abc/index.php/contentapi/discontent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:00" "GET /abc/index.php/data/dataContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:00" "GET /abc/index.php/Api/ApiContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:16" "GET /abc/index.php/Api/ApiContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:29" "GET /abc/index.php/Api/ApiContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:22" "GET /abc/index.php/htmlrequest/htmlContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:38" "GET /abc/index.php/htmlrequest/htmlContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:44" "GET /abc/index.php/htmlrequest/htmlContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:33" "GET /abc/index.php/Api/ApiContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:04" "GET /abc/index.php/site/siteContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:06" "GET /abc/index.php/data/dataContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:14" "GET /abc/index.php/data/dataContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http
"2011-09-07 17:00:51" "GET /abc/index.php/Api/ApiContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:33" "GET /abc/index.php/site/siteContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:45" "GET /abc/index.php/site/siteContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:59" "GET /abc/index.php/site/siteContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:02:00" "GET /abc/index.php/site/siteContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:02:09" "GET /abc/index.php/site/siteContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:00" "GET /abc/index.php/htmlrequest/htmlContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
"2011-09-07 17:00:09" "GET /abc/index.php/htmlrequest/htmlContent/4fd590d1762eb/ALL/allowed/1/all/all/1/http/
```

The above file i given a sample. the log file continuously grows.
     Expected output

```
/abc/index.php/contentapi/discontent/  - 3  
/abc/index.php/data/dataContent/  - 3  
/abc/index.php/Api/ApiContent/ - 5  
/abc/index.php/site/siteContent/ - 6  
/abc/index.php/htmlrequest/htmlContent/ - 5
```

Comment: what do you already try that failed ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there might've been some typos in the apache log, but how about this:

```
$ grep -o 'abc/[^ 0-9]*/' apache.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -r
6 abc/index.php/site/siteContent/
5 abc/index.php/htmlrequest/htmlContent/
5 abc/index.php/Api/ApiContent/
3 abc/index.php/data/dataContent/
2 abc/index.php/contentapi/discontent/
1 abc/index.php/contentapi/
```

Answer (score 0):

This extracts fourth field which is assumed to be the URL

`cat logfile | awk -F' ' '{print $4}' | awk -F'/' '{print $2"/"$3"/"$4"/"$5}' | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: Any time you see a solution that starts with `cat file` you know the poster doesn't know shell. Any time you see a solution that contains `awk ... | awk ...` you know the poster doesn't know awk. Any time you see a solution that uses the same hard-coded string (e.g. `"/"`) multiple times instead of `,` to use `OFS` to separate output fields you again know the poster doesn't know awk. Any time you see a solution that contains `sort | uniq` you again know the poster doesn't know shell. So I'd be wary of this solution as it contains many of the common red flags.

Comment: then you would know that there are hundreds of ways to solve a simple problem like this. the point is in trying to balance between "keep it simple stupid" and being accurate so that it works in all scenarios. If the user is asking for such command keeping it simple may be best

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{cnt[gensub(/(([/][^/]+){4}[/]).*/,"\\1","",$4)]++} END{for (url in cnt) print url " - " cnt[url]}' file
/abc/index.php/contentapi/discontent/ - 3
/abc/index.php/data/dataContent/ - 3
/abc/index.php/site/siteContent/ - 6
/abc/index.php/Api/ApiContent/ - 5
/abc/index.php/htmlrequest/htmlContent/ - 5
```